# openssl: How to configure private key size for secp256k1

Tags: openssl

I am trying to understand if it's possible to configure a private key size for the given curve.

```
openssl ecparam -name secp256k1 -genkey

-----BEGIN EC PARAMETERS-----
BgUrgQQACg==
-----END EC PARAMETERS-----
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHQCAQEEIMda3jdFuTnGd2Y9s9lZiQJXKSpxBp6WQWcurn4FnYogoAcGBSuBBAAK
oUQDQgAEI272v3lIoVkLZEbsJ/1l6Wfqbk8ZeybzzhtUN60EOhCRsR8rOLAIbbDl
ncOT1vtzEj5NZxQEYdopFMb10CfccQ
```

Was trying to read openssl documentation to see how to configure the length of the private key but failed to find anything regarding it. Could you advise?

Comment: You mean aside from the size specified by the curve name, e.g., 256 bits in secp256k1 vs the 224 bits in secp224k1?

Comment: You don't. 256 bits *is* the size of an EC key that is generated for sec256k1.

Comment: To avoid a common confusion: the size of the 'real' or 'raw' privatekey _value_, notated d, is determined by the curve and for secp256k1 is (exactly) 256 bits; but a privatekey _file_, one of which you posted, contains a good deal of other data in addition to d and thus _its_ size is larger than 256 bits. There are numerous existing Qs on this; if you can't find them I'll do a search for you. The main use of secp256k1 is in bitcoin, and unlike OpenSSL bitcoin software often uses only the d value, or a slight modification like WIF (Wallet Import Format) which adds one byte and encodes.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the explanation! So basically if I am choosing a curve named 256 I will get the key size of 256bits. That's what I could not understand. Thanks for the explanation!